# How to run a Windows Authenticated Asp.Net application in Local IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, .net-4.8

I like the ability to switch to Local IIS when I'm working on front end stuff that doesn't require a recompile (e.g. cshtml, css, and js files) because it saves me considerable time as the Visual Studio debugger can just attach to a continually running application hosted in IIS instead of stopping the application every time I stop the debugger and then having to start it again from scratch.

However, this is my first foray into working with a Windows Authenticated application and I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to make it run using Local IIS.

In IIS I have enabled Windows Authentication, and when I navigate to the application in a browser I am prompted to enter my credentials which is unexpected. And then when I enter my credentials they don't work and I am greeted with this message: "HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized".

There is a development server where I can deploy that works as expected, and as far as I am aware my Local IIS configuration matches the IIS Server on the development machine. Of course there's obviously something different though as it works on the development server and not on my local machine.

Well there is one difference. The app pool on the development server has a particular domain account. On my Local IIS app pool I have set it up to use my own personal account. I am doing this, as opposed to using the AppPoolIdentity account, because I need to access a SQL Server using integrated authentication and using AppPoolIdentity causes it to try to connect to SQL with my Computer rather than my Windows account.

So what am I missing here? Or what additional information can I provide to help you guys help me?